# SDL2 AntiAliasing

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, antialiasing

How to turn on antialiasing in SDL2, when using SDL_RenderCopyEx?

I find some articles that suggest to use:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 2);
```

and

```
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

But this makes no effect. Any ideas?

```
int Buffers, Samples;
SDL_GL_GetAttribute( SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, &Buffers );
SDL_GL_GetAttribute( SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, &Samples );
cout << "buf = " << Buffers << ", samples = " << Samples;
```

returns

buf = -858993460, samples = -858993460.

EDIT: CODE:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <SDL2/include/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/include/SDL_image.h>

using namespace std;


int main( int argc, char * args[] )
{
    // SDL Init
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
 
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 8);
    
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1); 

    // Create window
    SDL_Window *win = nullptr;
    win = SDL_CreateWindow("abc", 100, 100, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    
    if (win == nullptr) 
    {
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    

    int Buffers, Samples;
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute( SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, &Buffers );
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute( SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, &Samples );
    cout << "buf = " << Buffers << ", samples = " << Samples << ".";

    // Create Renderer
    SDL_Renderer *ren = nullptr;
    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    
    if (ren == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Create texture
    SDL_Texture *tex = nullptr;
    tex = IMG_LoadTexture(ren, "circle.png");

    SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(tex, 100);
    
    SDL_Rect s,d;
    SDL_Point c;
    s.x = s.y = 0;
    s.w = s.h = 110;

    d.x = 320;
    d.y = 240;
    d.w = d.h = 110;

    c.x = c.y = 55;

    // Event Queue
    SDL_Event e;
    bool quit = false;
    int angle = 0;

    while(!quit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
            //If user closes he window
            if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                quit = true;
        }
        angle += 2;

        float a = (angle/255.0)/M_PI*180.0;

        // Render
        SDL_RenderClear(ren);
        SDL_RenderCopyEx(ren, tex, &s, &d, a, &c, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
        SDL_RenderPresent(ren);


    }

    // Release
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);

    // Quit
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Do not worry about style or errors related to memory deallocation, etc. It was a quick sketch to test the possibility SDL'a

Comment: Have you created a context before you call get attribute?  the values you are reporting also look like they are reporting an uninitialised variable.

Comment: In each article / post I saw there was settings directly after SDL Init e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683094/sdl-opengl-multisampling-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're looking for an answer that doesn't require opengl use, then this may be of use:

```
SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1" );
```

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY

Comment: It is really old question :) I even don't remember what I was doing :) However thanks for your time. I believe that this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell by trying it out, the values are not set until the context is created, so if you run your `SDL_GL_GetAttribute` lines before creating the window you will get un-initialised values back as you are doing at present.

So to get correct values use the `SDL_GL_GetAttribute` call after creating a context and it should work fine.

Let me know how you get on, and if you need any more help/information I will help as I can.

**Addendum:**

You look like you have created the window before setting its properties, I have pasted some modified code, which should run fine (apologies, I can't test it until I get access to my home PC).

Rearranged code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <SDL2/include/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/include/SDL_image.h>

#include <gl/include/glew.h>

using namespace std;

void myInit()
{
    // SDL Init
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    // Settings
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 32);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 2);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1); 

    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
}

int main( int argc, char * args[] )
{
    myInit();   

    // Window Create
    SDL_Window *win = nullptr;
    win = SDL_CreateWindow("abc", 100, 100, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if(win == nullptr) return 1;

    // Create Renderer
    SDL_Renderer *ren = nullptr;
    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    if (ren == nullptr) return 1;

    int Buffers, Samples;
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute( SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, &Buffers );
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute( SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, &Samples );
    cout << "buf = " << Buffers << ", samples = " << Samples << ".";

    // Create texture
    SDL_Texture *tex = nullptr;
    tex = IMG_LoadTexture(ren, "circle.png");

    SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(tex, 100);
    SDL_SetTextureColorMod(tex, 255,0,0);

    SDL_Rect s,d;
    SDL_Point c;
    s.x = s.y = 0;
    s.w = s.h = 110;

    d.x = 320;
    d.y = 240;
    d.w = d.h = 220;

    c.x = c.y = 110;

    // Event Queue
    SDL_Event e;
    bool quit = false;
    int angle = 45.0*M_PI/180;

    while(!quit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
            //If user closes the window
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                quit = true;
        }

        // Render
        SDL_RenderClear(ren);
        SDL_RenderCopyEx(ren, tex, &s, &d, angle, &c, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
        SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    }

    // Release
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);

    // Quit
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After creating window and also after creating renderer the same result - no changes.

Comment: Any chance you could post some code?  may make tracking things down a bit easier.

Comment: btw. included "gl/include/glew.h" is only for glEnable().

Comment: sorry but nothing new :/

Comment: Sorry.. In SDL2 there is no SDL_SetVideoMode ;), but when I turn on fullscreen there is still no effect

Comment: removed, apologies, showing my age now, will be home soon and can test the code properly.

Comment: It would definitely help if you called `glEnable (GL_MULTISAMPLE)` ***after*** the render context has been created. Otherwise, the only thing this will do is generate a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

Comment: True, but this didnt changed anything.

Comment: I have tried the code in gcc and ms vs 2010 and 2012 and get the same results no matter how I change the code, will spend some time trying out more variations to see if it can be fixed.

Comment: This posted code is definitly not smoothing anything.

Comment: been a while but will review the code and repost soon:)